# Looping through object and setting as values in second object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array, which need to be the keys in my object.  I also have an object with the same keys and a default property, which I need to set as the value to my keys in the object I need to build.  I'm stuck at how to loop and set the key/values in the empty object. Thanks!!

`myFinalObj` starts off as an empty object.

My starting object

```
var startingObj = {
  'one' : {'default': 1, 'name': 'un'},
  'two' : {'default': 2, 'name': 'deux'},
  'three': {'default': 3, 'name': 'trois'}
}
```

My Array

```
var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

My finished Object

```
var myFinalObj = {
  'one' : 1,
  'two' : 2,
  'three' : 3
}
```

Comment: if each position of the `startingObj`, you have the key, why you need `myArray`?

Comment: Maybe I don't? But then how would I loop the data to get the object desired?

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to do your (home)work for you, but to answer *specific* questions about problems you're having. Try some things yourself, you might come up with the answer on your own, and if not, identify specific questions you can ask.

Comment: you would get 10 different answer here you haven't showed us what you've tried to get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myFinalObj = myArray.reduce((memo, name) => { 
  memo[name] = startingObj[name].default 
  return memo 
}, {})
```

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are a [recent](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) addition to javascript, and if your environment [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) them you can use the more verbose but equivalent :

```
 var myFinalObj = myArray.reduce(function(memo, name) { 
  memo[name] = startingObj[name].default 
  return memo 
}, {})
```

For IE < 9 the reduce function is also not available but you can use the polyfill available in the same [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) .

Comment: Could you explain this answer please?

Comment: I have added an explanation. Please review and let me know if any more clarifications are required.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var startingObj = {
  'one': {
    'default': 1,
    'name': 'un'
  },
  'two': {
    'default': 2,
    'name': 'deux'
  },
  'three': {
    'default': 3,
    'name': 'trois'
  }
}


var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var finalObject = {};

myArray.forEach(function(value){
 finalObject[value] = startingObject[value]['default']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set property keys using `obj["key"]=value` syntax, so this should work:

```
var myFinalObject={};
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    myFinalObj[myArray[i]]=startingObj[myArray[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Recommend using `for(.. in ..)` or `for (var i=0;i<..;i++)` as `Array.forEach` might not be supported in older browsers.**

```js
var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var startingObj = {
  'one' : {'default': 1, 'name': 'un'},
  'two' : {'default': 2, 'name': 'deux'},
  'three': {'default': 3, 'name': 'trois'}
}
var myFinalObj = {};
for (key in myArray) {
 myFinalObj[myArray[key]] = startingObj[myArray[key]].default;
}
console.log(myFinalObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var startingObj = {
  'one' : {'default': 1, 'name': 'un'},
  'two' : {'default': 2, 'name': 'deux'},
  'three': {'default': 3, 'name': 'trois'}
}

var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var myFinalObj = {}

for(n in myArray){
    if(startingObj.hasOwnProperty(myArray[n])){
        myFinalObj[myArray[n]] = startingObj[myArray[n]].default
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildObj(startObj, keyArr, finalObj) {
  var currKey;
  for (var i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++) {
    currKey = keyArr[i];
    finalObj[currKey] = startObj[currKey]['default'];
  }
}

var myFinalObj = {};
buildObj(startingObj, myArray, myFinalObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code:

```
var myFinalObj = {};
myArray.forEach(function(key){
    myFinalObj[key] = startingObj[key].default;
});
console.log(myFinalObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? Based on your test case listed above it seems to work.

```
  var startingObj = {
  'one' : {'default': 1, 'name': 'un'},
  'two' : {'default': 2, 'name': 'deux'},
  'three': {'default': 3, 'name': 'trois'}
}

var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var return_Obj = {}

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    for (var key in startingObj){
        if (key == myArray[i]){
           var val = startingObj[key]['default']
        break
        }

    }
    return_Obj[myArray[i]] = val
}

console.log(return_Obj)
```